# Using AuthorizeAttribute makes ErrorsController inaccessible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I read an article on using Global Filters to [default all MVC Controller Actions](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2013/06/authenticating-users-in-aspnet-mvc-4.aspx) to a 'white list' authentication practice & decided to try it out.

**SYMPTOMS:**
I did a quick test & the Controller Actions were correctly denied, but...

- Exception no longer raise in Global.ASAX's "Application_Error"...so it cannot redirect (anymore).
- The ErrorsController actions no longer fire...so the users never get redirected to custom errors
- Commenting-out the WEB.CONFIG entry below merely causes the page to show "Error 404.15 - Not Found"

The result is 404 NOT FOUND...which makes sense.  However, the redirect fails.  And as a result, the browser simply shows an empty, unstyled page.  Obviously, the user would never know it was **404 NOT FOUND** unless they were savvy enough to look in the console....which is bad.

**UPDATE:**
All of this code worked prior to these changes.  Adding the FILTER causes these symptoms.

**Below are the changes I made to conduct the test...am I missing something?**

**MY TEST-CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
    Exception unhandledException = Server.GetLastError();
    HttpException httpException = GetHttpException(unhandledException);

    if (httpException != null)
    {
        int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        switch (httpCode)
        {
            // These should redirect automatically.
            case (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
            case (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            case (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                return;
            default:
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                return;
        }
    }
}

public class FilterConfig
{
    #region <Methods>

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // FORCE: Authorize on all actions (by default)
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }

    #endregion
}

// The AUTHORIZE ATTRIBUTE is now defaulted on all actions...so we don't need it here
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    #region <Actions>

    [HttpGet]
    // The TEST is to see the ERRORS PAGE COME UP so put nothing here
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        // The user-call should be redirected to the error page when called...but oddly isn't
    }

    #endregion
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    #region <Actions>

    // GET: /Errors/Unexpected
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Unexpected()
    {
        TraceHandler.TraceIn(TraceLevel.Error);

        var unitOfWork = new ApplicationUnitOfWork();
        var viewModel = new UnExpectedErrorViewModel(unitOfWork);

        Response.StatusCode = (int)viewModel.StatusCode;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        TraceHandler.TraceOut();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // GET: /Errors/Forbidden
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Forbidden()
    {
        TraceHandler.TraceIn(TraceLevel.Error);

        var unitOfWork = new ApplicationUnitOfWork();
        var viewModel = new ForbiddenErrorViewModel(unitOfWork);

        Response.StatusCode = (int)viewModel.StatusCode;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;

        TraceHandler.TraceOut();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // GET: /Errors/NotFound
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        TraceHandler.TraceIn(TraceLevel.Error);

        var unitOfWork = new ApplicationUnitOfWork();
        var viewModel = new NotFoundErrorViewModel(unitOfWork);

        Response.StatusCode = (int)viewModel.StatusCode;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        TraceHandler.TraceOut();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**THE WEB CONFIG LOOKS LIKE:**
Of course, all this was previously hooked-up in the web.config to run correctly.  And, in fact, this does run prior to the test-conditions.

```
<!-- CUSTOM ERRORS: httpErrors -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/yourapplication/errors/forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/yourapplication/errors/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/yourapplication/errors/unexpected" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: have you specified in wbe.config to redirect where on error or 404

Comment: UPDATED question...thx

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your `ErrorController` with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. Basically, by registering a global filter as:

```
// FORCE: Authorize on all actions (by default)
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

You were forcing your users to see the errors if they are logged in. If you still want to do that then you have to skip your `ErrorController` from this filter(which `AllowAnonymousAttribute` does for you.)

Now coming back to your web.config, you don't need to add that section there. You can handle the statuscodes in your 'Application_Error' method as below:

```
        protected void Application_Error()
        {
            var exception = Server.GetLastError();
            var httpException = exception as HttpException;
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
            routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            if (httpException != null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
                switch (Response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case 403:
                        routeData.Values["action"] = "Forbidden";
                        break;

                    case 404:
                        routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";
                        break;

                   case 500:
                        routeData.Values["action"] = "UnExpected";
                        break;
                }
            }

            IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
            var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            errorsController.Execute(rc);
        }
```

You are probably getting 404 as your path seem to be wrong. What is `yourapplication` doing in those paths?

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/unexpected" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: @PrisonerZERO please check ending section of my answer

Comment: FYI...the path is correct.  But ONLY when running on local IIS because "locally" the root-url is "http://localhost/yourapplication/".  When in production, your edits are the correct entries. I use transforms to alter the production entries...so these are good.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO You dont need to specify the application there. MVC cannot find that path and hence giving you 404 not found errors

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  And creates other issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299972/why-is-my-query-string-so-long

I even commented-out the web.config entries.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO No, the thing is you must allow the user to login first and not put [Authorize] for login too. You will have to decorate Login method with [AllowAnonymous] attribute so that user is able to access that method irrespective of your global filter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `httpErrors` use `customErrors` element under `System.Web` in web config:

```
 <system.web>

    <customErrors mode="On">
            <error statusCode="500"
                   redirect="~/Error/Index" />
            <error statusCode="404"
                   redirect="~/Error/Index" />
        </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Here **Error** is the controller name and **Index** is the action.